# Sending simultaneous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aneeljmnclggefejjbbbbploekjpfejc) that finds all titles on pages like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aAnime_of_2011) and then sends a request to [myanimelist.net](http://myanimelist.net/) to get the title's rating. The ratings are then inserted into the page.

A page contains about 100 titles, so the extension needs to perform 100 HTTP requests. Is it OK to do all 100 requests at once, or should I wait until one request is completed before sending the next one?

Is there a way to cache the results so that I don't need to redo the requests if the page is refreshed?

Comment: There is no harm in performing 100 requests at once, your browser does it this way when pulling page resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run 100 requests at once a destination server might block you, depending on its settings. I would rather send requests in small batches, like 5 at once.

You can cache results in `localStorage` if you need persistence between browser restarts, or just in a background page variable space, if you don't.